# XMLStream Reader Scala - Proper Handle of END_DOCUMENT

Tags: xml, scala, stream, xmlstreamreader

I am actually restructuring an existing large software and switching from `XMLEventReader` to
`XMLStreamReader` for memory efficiency purposes.

Consider following definition of a function which currently just read XML event and prints them:

```
def evalStreamReader(source: StreamSource): Unit

    val StreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(source)
    while (StreamReader.hasNext) {
      val eventType = StreamReader.getEventType
      eventType match {
        case 1 => println("Start Element " + eventType + " : " + StreamReader.getLocalName)
        case 2 => println("End Element " + eventType + " : " + StreamReader.getLocalName)
        case 4 => println("Characters " + eventType + " : " + StreamReader.getText)
        case 7 => println("Start Document " + eventType)
        case 8 => println("End Document: " + eventType)

      }
      StreamReader.next()
    }
}
```

and the simple XML file :

```
<a>
  <c></c>
</a>
```

The output would be :

```
Start Document 7
Start Element 1 : a
Characters 4 : 
  
Start Element 1 : c
End Element 2 : c
Characters 4 : 

End Element 2 : a
```

Is there anyway I can handle the event `END_DOCUMENT` separately/correctly within the `While` condition/case matching, and not outside the loop? I tried many conditions and `do while` but no success.

The idea is that `StreamReader.next()` will switch the cursor the `END_DOCUMENT` event and `hasNext` will return false by its definition in the API:

```
boolean hasNext()
         throws XMLStreamException
Returns true if there are more parsing events and false if there are no more events. 
This method will return false if the current state of the XMLStreamReader is END_DOCUMENT
```

Comment: But what's your problem that doesn't let you this what you want? The code for end document is never called when inside while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample naive non-idiomatic approach:

```scala
def evalStreamReader(source: StreamSource): Unit = {
  val streamReader: XMLStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(source)
  var finished: Boolean = false

  do {
    val eventType = streamReader.getEventType

    if (eventType != 8) {
      eventType match {
        case 1 => println("Start Element " + eventType + " : " + streamReader.getLocalName)
        case 2 => println("End Element " + eventType + " : " + streamReader.getLocalName)
        case 4 => println("Characters " + eventType + " : " + streamReader.getText)
        case 7 => println("Start Document " + eventType)
      }
      streamReader.next()
    } else {
      println("End Document: " + eventType)
      finished = true
    }
  } while(!finished)
  streamReader.close()
}
```

It would output:

```
Start Document 7
Start Element 1 : a
Characters 4 : 
  
Start Element 1 : c
End Element 2 : c
Characters 4 : 

End Element 2 : a
End Document: 8
```

basically you need to separate flow control from the reader.